# Getting `find` to work in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, find

I am guessing I am overlooking something simple, since this seems like it should be a very straightforward task, but I am coming up short and can't seem to find anything on forums.

I am trying to run `find` from within a shell script and it is just not doing anything.

For example, I have a folder, with some files and a couple subdirectories with files as well:

```
$ ls *
afile1.txt  anotherfile.py  findit.sh

subdir1:
morefiles1.txt  morefiles2.txt  morefiles3.txt  somescript.py

subdir2:
evenmorefiles1.txt  evenmorefiles2.py  evenmorefiles2.sh
```

I want to use find to pull out all filenames with a given search string (and ultimately pipe to `xargs`), but I cannot seem to figure out why the exact same command works from the command line but not from within the shell script:

```
$ cat findit.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo $(which find)
echo "find . -name '"$1"' -print0"
find . -name '"$1"' -print0
echo "nothin??"
$ . findit.sh '*py'
/usr/bin/find
find . -name '*py' -print0
nothin??
$ find . -name '*py' -print0
./anotherfile.py./subdir2/evenmorefiles2.py./subdir1/somescript.py
```

I appreciate any help on this front...

Comment: Variables are not expanded inside single quotes (`'"$1"'`)

Comment: @ Nick have a look at this: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Answer (score 1):

You're quoting the double quotes, `-name '"$1"'`. Because you're using single quotes, the string is a literal four characters, *double-quote dollar number-one double-quote*.

However, even if you swap the double quotes and single quotes `-name "'$1'"` you'll still have single quotes in your string. So if `$1` is `dog` you'll be trying to match on the five character string `'dog'`.

If you're looking for files matching `*.py` then your script is correctly setting `$1`, but you want to use that expression like this

```
find . -name "$1" -print0
```